# Outer products using theano/numpy.tensordot

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, theano

I have a NumPy array of `n=3` vectors of length `m=10`, so `input.shape = (n,m,1)`. I am trying to compute the outer products of each vector using `theano/numpy.tensordot` such that the `output.shape = (n,m,m)` and :

```
output[i] = np.dot(input[i],input[i].T) = np.outer(input[i],input[i])
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible, but am having a hard time figuring out what arguments to use for axes. This can be easily done iterating over the array, but I am trying to complete this step using tensordot as it is implemented the same in theano and numpy.  This is important because I am using theano, but using numpy to debug currently.

Comment: `np.tensordot(b, np.transpose(b, axes=(0,2,1)), (2,1))` gets me close to what I want with a shape of `(3,10,3,10)` or `(n,m,n,m)`.  The correct values can be accessed by `(x,:,x,:)` , this however seems terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not exactly using the sum reduction part of a dot product and just broadcasting elementwise multiiplication for each row with it's transposed version. This could be achieved in a vectorized manner for all rows again with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by creating `singleton` dimensions in two versions of the input array - One with `singleton dim` at `axis=1` and another at `axis=2`. Since, the input array is already 3D shaped, so we already have the `version #2` with us. To get the first version, just swap axes along the last two dims. Thus, multiplying these two versions would give us the desired output, like so -

```
output = input*input.swapaxes(1,2)
```

Comment: Looking at this I realized that the dimensions of the original matrix should be `input.shape = (n,m,1)`.  The extra dimension is needed to make `np.dot(input[i],input[i].T) == np.outer(input[i],input[i])`.  Thus this solution only calculates the diagonal of what I am looking for: the `output.shape = (3,1)` instead of `(3,4,4)`

Comment: @jpsety If `input.shape = (n,m,1)` and `output[i] = np.dot(input[i],input[i].T) ` is the output you are after, you can get that in a vectorized manner with `input*input.swapaxes(1,2)`. Let me know if this works, I will edit my answer accordingly.